# Network.getResponseBody via Websocket API

Tags: websocket, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-devtools-protocol

I'm wondering if anyone might have any experience with Chrome Devtools Protocol via Websocket API, specifically with regards to extracting the Network response bodies in real time. I've taken a look at https://www.igvita.com/2012/04/09/driving-google-chrome-via-websocket-api/ which has a good initial example that shows how to enable to Network and navigate to a page, but I'm looking for whether or not it might be possible to a) navigate to pages at my leisure while b) recording the subsequent response bodies in real time/how to do this via Websocket API (or any language for that matter). Thanks for any insight.